# When I send a mutation request to chaskiq graphql endpoint I get "Data not found"

Tags: graphql

I have been using [Chaskiq](https://github.com/chaskiq/chaskiq) for some work but ran into an error.
I built from source on Ubuntu 20.04.
I got the graphql part working and query requests work. However, whenever I make a mutation request I seem to get this response:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Data not found",
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Example mutation request I sent to get the response above:

```js
mutation updateAppUser($appKey: String!, $options: Json!, $id: Int!) {
  updateAppUser(appKey: $appKey, options: $options, id: $id) {
    appUser {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
}
```

I have the variables Query Variables as below:

```js
{
    "appKey": <My_APP_KEY>,
    "options": {
        "name": <Custom_Name>
    },
    "id": <My_ID>
}
```

Please help me know the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Data not found` is returned when the server does not found any record.

basically ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound , so you are probably trying to find the wrong record. check the logs to see what's happening